# Cannot invoke with an argument list of type '(UInt64)'

Tags: ios, swift, uint64, uint8t

I am building a robotic arm and going to control the arm with an iOS application. I am having trouble sending the position to the arduino bluetooth 4.0 shield.

I am using sliders to control the position of the arm.

There are TWO errors.

1. "cannot invoke 'writePosition' with an argument list of type '(UInt8)'"
2. "cannot invoke 'sendPosition' with an argument list of type '(UInt64)'"

   ```
   func sendPosition(position: UInt8)         
   if !self.allowTX {
       return
   }

   // Validate value
   if UInt64(position) == lastPosition {
       return
   }
   else if ((position < 0) || (position > 180)) {
       return
   }

   // Send position to BLE Shield (if service exists and is connected)
   if let bleService = btDiscoverySharedInstance.bleService {
       bleService.writePosition(position) ***1)ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE***
       lastPosition = position

       // Start delay timer
       self.allowTX = false
       if timerTXDelay == nil {
           timerTXDelay = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerTXDelayElapsed"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
       }
     }
   }

   func timerTXDelayElapsed() {
   self.allowTX = true
   self.stopTimerTXDelay()

   // Send current slider position
   self.sendPosition(UInt64(self.currentClawValue.value)) **2)ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE**
   ```

   }

Here is my "writePosition" function.

```
func writePosition(position: Int8) {
    // See if characteristic has been discovered before writing to it
    if self.positionCharacteristic == nil {
        return
    }

    // Need a mutable var to pass to writeValue function
    var positionValue = position
    let data = NSData(bytes: &positionValue, length: sizeof(UInt8))
    self.peripheral?.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: self.positionCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
}
```

I don't know if I am leaving something out or totally missing something. 
I have tried simple conversions between UInt8 and UInt64 but those have not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the different int types you're using.

First let's check the `writePosition` method. You use an `Int8` as parameter. So you need to make sure that you also call the method with a `Int8` as parameter. To make sure you are using an `Int8` you can cast it:

```
bleService.writePosition(Int8(position))
```

As you see here, you need to cast the `position` to `Int8`.

Now check your `sendPosition` method. There you've got a similar problem. You want a `UInt8` as parameter, but you call it with a `UInt64` parameter. That's something you can't do. You need to use the same integer type:

```
self.sendPosition(UInt8(self.currentClawValue.value))
```

Here it's the same. Use `UInt8` instead of `UInt64` to make the casting work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but the error indicates you're calling 'writePosition' with an argument list of type '(UInt8)'

However, writePosition's parameter list specifies an Int8.  Either change writePosition's parameter type to UInt8, or change (or cast) the calling parameter to Int8.

Likewise, with sendPosition, it wants a UInt8, but you're sending it a UInt64.

Swift is fussier in that it complains about implicit type conversions.

You should either use the integer size that best fits your data, or that the API requires you to use.